# Error: default constructor is already defined

Tags: inheritance, constructor, dart

In Dart, I have the following code:

```dart
class FirstClass {
  FirstClass(a) {

  }
}

class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

}
```

This causes and error on `SecondClass` because the `FirstClass` does not have a default constructor.

However when I try to add one.

```dart
class FirstClass {
  FirstClass(a) {

  }

  FirstClass() {

  }
}
```

It errors because the default constructor is already defined in `FirstClass`.

The only way I can seem to make this work and not error is if the superclass does not implement any constructors at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In dart you can not have the same method/constructor name used several times (even with different parameters).

In your case you can either use named constructor to define 2 constructors :

```dart
class FirstClass {
  FirstClass() {}
  FirstClass.withA(a) {}
}
```

or define `a` as optional and keep only one constructor :

```dart
class FirstClass {
  FirstClass([a]) {}
}
```

Comment: And the reason is Dart is not statically typed and thus cannot use parameter types to differentiate/overload the same method/constructor name.

Comment: @Icn Dart is essentially statically typed, if you define something as an String you won't be able to put nothing inside that's not at string at compilation time. Dynamic is an exception and it's not a good justification for removing method overloading altogether. It could have been restricted only to cases when there's actual ambiguity, exactly like in Java (for example, with generics and erasure).

Answer (score 0):

In dart you cannot have multiple constructor as other language like java.

You can define default constructor as

```
class FirstClass {
  FirstClass() {}
}
```

OR

```
class FirstClass {
  String name;
  int age;
  FirstClass(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

You can not have default as well as parameter constructor in it.